# How do I get the first five columns of a dataframe in a txt file?

Tags: linux, awk

I want to save the first five columns in `log2ratios.txt` as `output.txt`.

```
awk -v b=1 -v e=5 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=b;i<=e;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<e ? OFS : ORS)}' log2ratios.txt >> output.txt
```

I've also tried:
`cut -d, -f1-5 log2ratios.txt >> output.txt`

Current output (snapshot):

```
    ProbeSetName    Chromosome  Position    Log2Ratio   m$Log2Ratio m$Log2Ratio m$Log2Ratio m$Log2Ratio m$Log2Ratio m$Log2Ratio m$Log2Ratio m$Log2Ratio,,,,
1   CN_473963   1   51586   -0.574911   -0.409836   0.072711    -0.345886   -0.441539   -0.11781    -0.426072   -0.611897   -0.060026,,,,
2   CN_473964   1   51659   -0.256262   -0.214604   -0.153238   -0.051997   -0.472509   -0.156168   -0.263254   -0.326569   -0.339877,,,,
```

Desired output:

`output.txt` should contain the following information.

```
> as.data.frame( r[,1:5], drop=false)
     ProbeSetName Chromosome Position Log2Ratio m.Log2Ratio
1       CN_473963          1    51586 -0.574911   -0.409836
2       CN_473964          1    51659 -0.256262   -0.214604
3       CN_473965          1    51674 -0.030027   -0.322802
4       CN_473981          1    52771 -0.399400   -0.657841
5       CN_473982          1    52788 -0.118232   -0.840977
6       CN_497981          1    62627  0.150264   -0.244675
7       CN_502615          1    75787 -0.669798   -1.320492
8       CN_502613          1    75849 -0.125760   -0.145890
9       CN_502614          1    76175 -1.654274   -2.419629
10      CN_502616          1    76192 -2.385214   -2.417917
11      CN_502843          1    88453 -0.591260   -0.501315
12      CN_466171          1   218557 -0.374847   -0.367135
13      CN_468414          1   218926  0.797292    0.818930
14      CN_468412          1   219009  0.356342    0.273622
15      CN_468413          1   219024  0.164000   -0.111701
16      CN_470565          1   219470  0.721352    0.399291
17      CN_468424          1   225521 -0.190690   -0.077926
18      CN_468425          1   225579 -0.667092   -0.212682
19      CN_460512          1   346294 -0.524201   -0.516528
20      CN_460513          1   346393  0.258182    0.013902
21  SNP_A-8575125          1   554484  0.326082    0.361037
22  SNP_A-8575115          1   554636  0.021981   -0.249903
23  SNP_A-8575371          1   557616  0.269811   -0.039262
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1813241 rows ]
```

data:

```
head log2ratios.txt
        ProbeSetName    Chromosome      Position        Log2Ratio       m$Log2Ratio     m$Log2Ratio     m$Log2Ratio    m$Log2Ratio      m$Log2Ratio     m$Log2Ratio     m$Log2Ratio     m$Log2Ratio
1       CN_473963       1       51586   -0.574911       -0.409836       0.072711        -0.345886       -0.441539      -0.11781 -0.426072       -0.611897       -0.060026
2       CN_473964       1       51659   -0.256262       -0.214604       -0.153238       -0.051997       -0.472509      -0.156168        -0.263254       -0.326569       -0.339877
3       CN_473965       1       51674   -0.030027       -0.322802       -0.59208        -0.305452       -0.092585      -0.227589        -0.18488        -0.339897       -0.211489
4       CN_473981       1       52771   -0.3994 -0.657841       -0.537569       -0.695869       -0.27919        -0.236683       -0.428801       -0.49314        -0.364471
5       CN_473982       1       52788   -0.118232       -0.840977       -0.329929       -0.448378       -0.308569      -0.315758        -0.511238       -0.518504       -0.372665
6       CN_497981       1       62627   0.150264        -0.244675       -0.127441       0.042639        -0.111781      0.061487 -0.045214       -0.19797        -0.088062
7       CN_502615       1       75787   -0.669798       -1.320492       -0.836021       -0.702558       -0.427371      -0.454593        -0.721925       -0.191238       -0.513743
8       CN_502613       1       75849   -0.12576        -0.14589        -0.298104       -0.136768       -0.272062      0.214592 -0.021858       -0.07202        -0.365969
9       CN_502614       1       76175   -1.654274       -2.419629       -1.918768       -1.56881        -1.65782       -0.525656        -0.873399       -0.889187       -0.670121
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with `awk '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5}' log2ratios.txt > output.txt`?

Comment: @jared_mamrot it still doesn't subset the columns.

Comment: Are you able to please post the output from `head log2ratios.txt`? (From the command line, not via R)

Comment: @jared_mamrot ok added to the question.

Comment: If we need scrollbars to see your sample input/output then you posted too much data. You're supposed to create and post a [mcve] that concisely demonstrates your problem, not just throw up whatever data you have lying around. See [ask]. Please [edit] your question to fix that and explain what [it still doesn't subset the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71283547/how-do-i-get-the-first-five-columns-of-a-dataframe-in-a-txt-file#comment126001542_71283547) means.

Comment: @melolili what separators are used in your `log2ratios.txt` file? Why do you assume that it is `,` judging from your `FS=","` whilst there is not single `,` in your file? Why you want to process dataframe in `AWK` rather than `R` for which dataframes are native?

Comment: you are pretending it is a CSV file. use your actual field delimiter    and your `cut` should work fine

Comment: Did you solve your problem @melolili ?  Or do you still want help?